# How can Property Descriptor gets values of two controls using same code line?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, webforms

I found this code in one of the project developed by an Ex-Employee for custom gridview with custom controls which works fine but I am not sure what exactly it is doing,

**CODE**:

```
public class aBoundField : ImageField
{
    //here I got some get set properties defined
    protected override void OnDataBindField(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;

        PropertyDescriptor propertyA = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);
        PropertyDescriptor propertyB = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);

        PropertyAFieldValue = this.GetValue(control.NamingContainer, this._PropertyAField, ref propertyA).ToString();
        PropertyBFieldValue = this.GetValue(control.NamingContainer, this._PropertyBField, ref propertyB).ToString();
            base.OnDataBindField(sender, e);
    }
```

What's happening in  `OnDataBindField` method especially when it is getting PropertyDescriptor. I did bit research and figured out that it is a property bag, but if it is a property bag How would it know what value is for property A or Property B in this code.

```
 PropertyDescriptor propertyA = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);
 PropertyDescriptor propertyB = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);
```

**What I don't exactly understand is**

How can **Property Descriptor**  gets values of two controls using same code line

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true)
```

How would above code line will figure out if its for Property A or Property B.

I tried to get values from one property descriptor thinking its a property bag but it didn't worked properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GetValue(control.NamingContainer, this._PropertyAField, ref propertyA)
```

ProperyA is given as a reference therefor everything that happens to propertyA inside that method will update propertyA that was defined above.

using

```
PropertyDescriptor propertyA = null;
```

instead of

```
PropertyDescriptor propertyA = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);
```

will still work.

**Further Reading**
[ref method parameter keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: +1, I don't want to believe you but it is working when I put null for both of properties, how strange, but am still confused.

Comment: Basically you are sharing the same reference of the variable in the memory. when u update the variable, every variable pointing towards the same reference will be updated. Doesnt matter where or in what class its being used.

Comment: thanks, but what PropertyDescriptor  in porpertyA is getting, or what does Type Descriptor if getting :S

Comment: nothing is being changed to TypeDescriptor as this is just being used to assign the first value. I assume he just gave it a random value to initialise the variable. The variable has to have a reference in the memory assigned to it in order to work with the ref parameter. Unless you use 'out' which is pretty much the same as returning a value

Comment: this is what actually helped me understanding the process, but thanks for your help too :) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18066/Dynamic-Properties-A-Database-Created-At-Runtime

Answer (score 0):

In view of your most recent edit:

> How can Property Descriptor gets values of two controls using same code line

It can't. For some reason, the former employee wanted both `propertyA` and `propertyB` to be the same or there is a typo, and this is in actual fact a bug of some sort.

Comment: its not a answer, however propertyA and propertyB are boundfields in gridview, and code is trying to get there values using property descriptor

Comment: @user13814 So what exactly us your question then? The code you have posted does just what you have said, it binds a value from a `propertybag` into `propertyA` and `propertyB`

Comment: How can you say it can't , when its happening in above code. are you saying above code is not valid ?

Comment: @user13814 The code does just as it says. There is no way from the code you have posted to know how the rest of the application knows the difference between `propertyA` and `propertyB`. When you test this application, does it function as it should? Do `propertyA` and `propertyB` behave as they should?