# How a property descriptor gets properties of two different bound fields?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

**I can't understand how a property descriptor gets properties of two different bound fields** by just saying `.Find("boundField", true)`

here is an example

```
PropertyDescriptor propertyA = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);
PropertyDescriptor propertyB = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(DataBinder.GetDataItem(control.NamingContainer)).Find("boundField", true);
```

Both code of lines are same and when I debug they return `null` but then when I try to get values out of them like this, they give out different values (which is right), how can this be possible ?

```
PropertyAFieldValue = this.GetValue(control.NamingContainer, this._PropertyAField, ref propertyA).ToString();
PropertyBFieldValue = this.GetValue(control.NamingContainer, this._PropertyBField, ref propertyB).ToString();
```

For rest of code check this out [How can Property Descriptor gets values of two controls using same code line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429933/what-is-this-code-for)